# Where is the "Up" button in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

The Google Toolbar has a useful feature, the **Up** button:

[image]

i miss the feature in Chrome, so i went to install the Google Toolbar in Chrome.

Except you can't:

> You're using Chrome, that's great. All of the features of GoogleToolbar are already built into your browser.

[image]

Google is telling me that the **Up** button is already in Chrome.

Where is it?

Comment: What did the button even do?

Comment: @random see my answer, I think its right.

Comment: An “up button” is not nearly as useful for the Internet as it is for the local file-system.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're in luck, someone made it a Chrome Extension called [**Up.**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/iohgglcbddjknnemakghbjadinmopafl)

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: @JMK Ninja'd ;)

Comment: i have that extension; but unfortunately it doesn't function the same as the Google up button. But accepted anyway, since there likely is no up button in Google Chrome (and no Google Toolbar for Chrome)